# Selecting Data Template based on size

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

For the case, let's display a short information about an e-mail, which has sender, subject and body.

I construct 2 different `DataTemplate`'s: one that shows the sender and the subject, and another one that shows the sender, the subject and the first 3 non-empty lines of the body.

**Q**: How do I select a datatemplate based on how much of screen estate WPF can provide? If that is not the right approach, how do I show short-version-visual-representation vs. long-version-visual-representation based on available size?

---

What I did: I played with `DataTemplateSelector` but didn't find a way to reach the goal. The selector seems to operate only based on the data itself.

I created a control to show e-mail message and overrided `Measure(size)` and `Arrange(size)`. In `Measure(size)` I can do:

```
res1 = base.Measure(infSize); // non-restricted size
res2 = base.Measure(size);
```

and I know if res2 is smaller than res1, that means I need to render the short-version-visual-representation; but I'm stuck at this moment ...

Comment: Maybe this article is what you are looking for: http://learnwpf.com/post/2011/08/09/Changing-the-DataTemplate-based-on-the-Available-Space-e28093-SizeBasedTemplateSelector.aspx .

Comment: Yes, that code showed the way to solution.